# Using Publishing api in android to publish apk from android device

Tags: android, google-play-services, apk, publishing, android-developer-api

i want to create an android app which will allow to publish apk from my android device. i searched regarding Publishing API and referred [publishing-api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing) but it states that it is possible through Java app. I want to implement it in my android app. Is it possible to do that? Can i use publishing-api in android application?

Thank you.

Comment: your question can't be understood, please elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

An example on how to use the publishing api can be found here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api

This code can easily ported to android, just add the 
`compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v2-rev19-1.20.0'` dependency to your app and it should download all the required depenencies.

As Android apps also use Java you can basicaly just copy/paste the sample code and modifly it to your needs.

Comment: thank you. i looked at that code but how can i access all classes in android? i cant access them directly by just copy-paste

Comment: You need the dependencies as described above. Add them to your build file and they should be downloaded automatically. As an alternative you could also download the Google Play SDK and add the jar files to your build file as local dependency.

Comment: ok. i will try that. how can i access "/resources/client_secrets.json" in android app?

Comment: It's a basic file access. I would suggest not bundling the client secret with the app but to allow the user to store their own client secret. Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal